# Building a basement at or below water level?

Tags: basement, flooding

Is there a method for building a basement that would be at or slightly below water level?

We have a home that is built roughly 50 feet from a creek that's generally dry during spring and summer until it storms and then it fills fairly rapidly. I'm interested in building a basement level on the home, however I know I'm going to have to contend with water at some point and am attempting to research creative options to be minimize headaches for contending with water.

I suspect a pretty serious polymer layer will be necessary and I'm curious about what others have seen and experienced when faced with perhaps similar scenarios.

Comment: Is the site graded so part of the site is below the bottom of your basement?  If so, French or Buckeye drains...  Otherwise you may want to start referring to that basement as a "keel", kitchen as a "galley" etc.  If the water rises to where the basement is displacing more weight of water than the house weighs... it'll float!

Comment: LOL, well it's on a very slight grade, but no, it's not graded anywhere near to that degree.